# How to access another class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Right, i've searched high and low for an answer to this, but no-one seems to have the same issue as me. I've created 3 classes all of them movieclips. 2 of them are like buttons so when pressed I want the 3rd movieclip to move to the left or right but it comes up with error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property x through a reference with static type Class. The  3 classes are all linked in the fla file so not sure why it's not as simple as just typing the class name to access it. Anyway here is the code:

First class (which I want to move using a mouse press):

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Walking extends MovieClip
{
    public function Walking()
    {
        x = 600;
        y = 350;

        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}   

}
```

Second class:

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Left extends MovieClip
{
    public function Left()
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveleft);
    }

    protected function moveleft(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Walking.x += -10;
    }
}







}
```

Third Class: (havn't coded yet)

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Right extends MovieClip
{
    public function Right()
    {

    }
}







}
```

Comment: You are trying to access static property of class of Walking, you need to Instantiate a new object of type Walking then access the x property. You are indeed accessing another class currently but trying to access an invalid static property(x) you should read up again on classes in As3 and not get to ahead of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep your game logic in a single class and then reference the buttons. In this case you don't even need a class for the buttons (yet). 
Something like this ...

```
//Game.as
var arrowLeft : MovieClip;
var arrowRight : MovieClip;
var walker : MovieClip;

function Game()
{
    arrowLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickLeft);
    arrowRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickRight);
}

function OnClickLeft(pEvent : MouseEvent) : void
{
    Walk(-speed);
}

function OnClickRight(pEvent : MouseEvent) : void
{
    Walk(speed);
}

function Walk(pSpeed : Number) : void
{
    walker.x += pSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, I re-read some more on classes and it turns out I forgot about the document class. What I needed to do was to import the movieclips to stage using the document class (Thus creating instances of them, aka instantiation) and then I was able to access the x and y properties. I was confused as to what a class was and it is just code outside of the document class and fla that links to an object like a movieclip and runs separately to the document class through all instances of the object. Anyway here is what I have now, working fine :)

Document Class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import code.Walking;
import code.Left;
import code.Right;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class gameWalk extends MovieClip {

    public var walker:Walking;
    public var left:Left;
    public var right:Right;

    public function gameWalk()
    {
        walker = new Walking();
        left = new Left();
        right = new Right();

        addChild(walker);
        addChild(left);
        addChild(right);

        walker.x = 640;
        walker.y = 360;
        left.x = 65;
        left.y = 660;
        right.x = 1200;
        right.y = 660;

        createListeners()

    }

    public function createListeners():void
    {
        left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveLeft);
        right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveRight);
    }

    public function moveLeft(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        walker.x += -10;
    }

    public function moveRight(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        walker.x += 10;
    }
}

}
```

Walking:

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Walking extends MovieClip
{
    public function Walking()
    {
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}









}
```

Left:

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Left extends MovieClip
{
    public function Left()
    {

    }
}







}
```

Right:

```
package code
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Right extends MovieClip
{
    public function Right()
    {

    }
}







}
```